# Java delay before code

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to add a delay to my loop. It cannot be thread.sleep() because that sleeps the whole thread. I am trying to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. I know it's not 100% precise and that's fine.

```
long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 200;
boolean goAhead = false;

if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 201) { 
    goAhead = true; 
}

if (goAhead) {
    //Do something
    //atm this never happens. 
    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It seems this needs a `javax.swing.Timer` or `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: Please don't busy wait.  It eats CPU and electricity like there is no tomorrow.  Future, more powerful machines will just burn hotter each time it hits this code, possibly throwing away millions of executions for you to get your 200 milliseconds.  Sleep the thread, unless you are writing control systems within embedded hardware.

Comment: There's no difference between delaying your loop and sleeping the whole thread. The thread isn't doing anything except executing your loop. Question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Why 'sleeping the whole thread' is a problem? Anyway if you want to busy wait, do it in a `while` loop. `if` is one shot.

Comment: the problem with sleeping the hole thread is it sleeps everything..... since the thread contains alot of other stuff beside a loop. it stops everything else. cant bealive i have to explain this. but there you go.

Comment: Well, a "delay" **is** "stopping everything". So either you want to do something in your loop, and then just do it, or you want to wait some time in the loop to slow it down for whatever reason, and then use Thread.sleep(). A thread does one thing at a time, and in your case it's the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I might imagine the question could be:

Q: I have a callback on the GUI Event thread which must trigger an action on the same thread every 250 ms.  I can't have the GUI thread block for this amount of time because it freezes the GUI. What can I do?

A: Uses an executor to trigger a task periodcially on the GUI Event Thread.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // task to be perform periodically in the GUI Event Thread.
            }
        });
    }
}, 250, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The GUI thread which performs the task but the background thread which does the waiting.

---

I would write something more like

```
long time = 0;
while(condition) {
   long now = System.nanoTime();
   if (now >= time + 200e6) {
      // do something
      time = now;
   }
   // do something else
}
```

Without knowing the specific requirements of the program the code can be read as.

```
long time = 0; // a local variable or field as appropriate

// you have a loop around all code of interest at some level
// You could have a GUI event loop which you don't define but it is there.

// at some point your checking code is called.
   long now = System.nanoTime();
   if (now >= time + 200e6) {
      // do something
      time = now;
   }
```

This doesn't wait as such because you don't want anything to block. Instead it prevents the block of code being called closer than 200 ms apart.

---

```
int i = 0, count = 0;
long start = System.nanoTime();

long time = 0;
while (count < 20) {
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    if (now >= time + 200e6) {
        // do something e.g.
        count++;

        time = now;
    }
    // do something else
}
long runTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Performed something at %.3f per second%n", (count - 1) * 1e9 / runTime);
```

prints

```
Performed something at 5.000 per second
```

Comment: again this will hold everything. as soon as it gets to the loop.

Comment: Ok, now it can do something else as well. ;)

Comment: ....... useless comment is useless.

Comment: Indeed not sure how your comment helps me help you at all. BTW I am 4th rep in answering Java questions so if I can't help you, there are few that can.

Comment: let me tell you why its useless. 1. every code is before the while loop. so making it in the while loop. is pointless. 2. everysingle thing in the thread dont need the same condition. 3. this will still make anything wait untill the while loop is done. that means every overrides that touches this hook. will wait.

Comment: 1. So your code won't work if you move it?? 2. the condition can be `true` it up to you if it useful or not. 3. but how you break down this loop depends on you. There has to be a loop some where or the problem doesn't make sense and if this in the caller it doesn't make any difference. I am not sure why you can't adapt this code to you need because it not clear what these unstated needs are. We can't read your mind.

Comment: my code will work just fine if i move it. but if i move it into a while loop. everyting will hold. this is written in a hook. that overrides another hook. that means writting every code in a while loop. would make everything else never happen.. you dont need to read my mind. the question i ask is simple. how do i make it wait a 200ms. without making it sleep. while loops and thread.sleep have the same result in terms of holding everything else off.

Comment: " how do i make it wait" if you have no control over how or when I method will be called you cant wait so it doesn't make sense to say you want to wait. All you can do is do nothing if it is called less than 200 ms apart which has nothing to do with waiting. I assumed that any repeating function would be inside a loop of some kind. Are you saying there is no loop at any level?

Comment: let me give you some more code. mabye you understand then.                   for(Object o : anArrayList) { 
if(some anArrayList Conditions)                                      //wait for 200ms                                                            //Do something and then break; the loop. the arrayList conditions are taken from the hook parments that are updated every tick. doing a while loop anywhere would hold everything.

Comment: Unless you have an outer loop which has all the code of interest inside it. If you have to, it can be at the Runnable.run() level. You have to have one loop at some level or the method might not be called more than once.

Comment: just forget it. your talking about making another runnable thread now. if i do that nothing will work. tried telling you this before. the conditions are from the hook parments. a run() method cannot have parments. if i wanted a runnable thread. i would have use thread.sleep insted. just forget it. ill figure it out my self

Comment: "your talking about making another runnable thread now." Thats not what I suggested at all. You don't seem to be very aware of how your own program works. Every thread has a Runnable at the top level and you can't run anything without it. What is a "parment"? I couldn't find this word using google.

Comment: @overrides
public void something(something yup, something2 yup2) {
yup and yup2 are what i call parments. it might be spelled wrong in english.

Comment: Ok, if we assume there may or may not be a loop somewhere else which calls this in code, which doesn't matter to you at the moment, all you need to do is add the code in the second example I gave. This code assume that if it ignores calls less than 200ms apart it can do this because will be called again later after 200 ms. Thus the need for a loop or repeated calls at some level.

Comment: i tried your code. does 100% the same thing as mine. a hole alot of nothing.

Comment: You said only "Can anyone help with this?" so I suggested a more elegant way of doing it e.g. no `boolean` field. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: the thing i had in mind was to make the thing wait for 200ms before performing a task. atm the task is performed around 80 times per sec with your code. am not the greatest at math but thats quite alot more than 5times per sec.

Comment: 200e6 ns is 200ms or 5 times per second or less. And you have already stated you don't want the thread to wait because it would hold up everything else. What you haven't stated is what you actually wanted help with. I have added an example which measures that after the first call, it is called 5 times per seconds.

Comment: i said forget it. i tried you new code. and it does 100% what i expect it to. since its a while loop. it holds everything else. and stops everything in every class. what this will do. is take my programs. my jframes and everything. turn them from 460 fps. to an nonfunctional program with 0 fps.

Comment: which why you wouldn't add a loop as you already have one and you would only use the code in the second example.

Comment: Well, I've read these threads three times now, and I'm still completely confused :(  There seems to be two completely conficiting requirements that cannot possibly be both satisfied.  I'll read it all again later tonight after I get back from the pub after watching 'Match of the Day' - maybe it'll become clearer after six pints of Doombar.

Comment: What I would like to know is what he would like help with. He has noted that the second example works much the same as the example he gave in the original question, which is true just a little nicer IMHO, but he didn't say why this was a problem and what he was looking for.

Comment: none of the examples work. dont go around telling lies. the secound example does nothing. allready said that. heres my what i said about your example "i tried your code. does 100% the same thing as mine. a hole alot of nothing. – Coders Rock 3 hours ago "

Comment: @CodersRock I didn't know what you mean by that. You remember me saying that the code has to be called repeatedly. I would assume it doesn't do anything because its only called once. i.e. it doesn't do anything the first time and because its not called again it never does anything. How you call it repeatedly depends on what the caller does which you didn't say (I suggested you didn't know) I am guessing its in the GUI Event thread. The GUI Event Thread doesn't have delayed events, but you can use a separate thread to trigger this.  You said you can't use another thread but I can't guess why.

Comment: @CodersRock Just guessing, but above is how I would answer a question which many or many not have anything to do with what you are asking for (because I'm not a mind reader ;)

Comment: its called onUpdate. that means it is called repeatly.

Comment: I have provided two different example which do work. Can you provide a self contained example which doesn't work?

Comment: OK, I'm nicely pissed up now.   Is this thread a GUI thread that must respond in a timely manner to messages/signals/slots from I/O events?  If so, you cannot wait in a GUI event handler.  You should split up your code/data into a state-machine that can be called by a timer event after the required interval so as to satisfy your requirements.  I'm sorry, but we're all struggling with a delay that must not actually delay.  A thread can only follow one execution path at a time: that's why they're called threads.

Comment: @peter lawrey like i said none of the examples work.

Comment: None of the example work for you because you are running code we cannot see and do not understand. I get the impression you need to spend more time understanding it yourself. All the example work for me and you cannot provide an example which does not work for me either so I don't see how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 2):

the reason why it does not work is

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() -lastTime > 201) { goAhead= true; }
```

is executed once and that's it, you need to put it into a loop eg

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() -lastTime < 201) {
// wait
}
```

however it will give you ca. 100% cpu usage for nothing and it is a poor design I believe

Comment: Hi Bela we know each other. From b2i :)

Comment: +1 Never wait using a loop. Instead use signals and wait methods

Comment: the loop will break when the condition are meet. anyway so its fine it only happens once.

Comment: @BelaVizer: I'm David. I sat in front of you near the window until I left in 09.

Comment: @zeller great :), that is pretty funny that we bump into each other on StackOverFlow, hope you are doing well

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to wait is to use `Thread.sleep()` (or `Object.wait()` with a timeout); it blocks the thread, but it does so in a predictable way. If you absolutely must do things while waiting, either put the sleep *or* the other work in a separate thread and use the inter-thread coordination primitives to synchronize things.

```
final Thread mainthread = Thread.currentThread();
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        mainthread.interrupt();
    }
}.start();

while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    // Do your other work here...
}
```

Threads are (comparatively) cheap in Java. Use them.

Comment: read what i say I'm trying to add a delay to my loop. It cannot be thread.sleep() because that sleeps the whole thread. i am still aware about the fact that i cut put it into another thread and make it sleep in a runnable. it that would mean no of my other par's can be use. beause there called in a hook that overrides another hook. please stop telling me to use something that i allready told you i know about and that i cant use. am not saying it for fun. i cant thread.sleep is it hard to understand? i cant use it. understand?

Comment: @Coders Why don't you tell us why you want to slow your loop down? It's usual to want to speed loops up…

Comment: And the code sample will work just fine; it puts the delay in the separate thread so you can keep doing things. Just probe with `Thread.interrupted()` (the simplest mechanism for this) from time to time to see if you're done yet.

Comment: the sample will not work at all. my parments that are taken from a hook that overrides another hook. cannot be added in a runnable.